# Role of Mutiple "layout" arguments to go-fiber html Render

Tags: go, go-fiber

I want to understand how go-fiber [Render](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/gofiber/template/html#Engine.Render) works with multiple `layout` arguments. It is quite clear how a single `layout` argument works (the first argument is executed and inserted into the `{{embed}}` tag inside the first `layout` argument). I looked at the sources and it appears to my inexperienced golang eye that only `layout[0]` is used. Can someone familiar with go-fiber templating explain please. Thanks